# merge two big dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two big data frame : one containes 3M rows and the other contains 2M rows
1st dataframe :

```
    sacc_id$    id$     creation_date
0   0011200001LheyyAAB  5001200000gxTeGAAU  2017-05-30 13:25:07
```

2nd dataframe :

```
    sacc_id$    opp_line_id$    oppline_creation_date
0   001A000000hAUn8IAG  a0WA000000BYKoWMAX  2013-10-26
```

I need to merge them :

```
case = pd.merge(limdata, df_case, left_on='sacc_id$',right_on='sacc_id$')
```

But I get A memory problem:

```
pandas/_libs/join.pyx in pandas._libs.join.inner_join()

MemoryError:
```

Is there another way to do it efficiently. I read in some discussion here that Dask can help but i do not understand how to use it in this context.

Any help please?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `Dask` when you are dealing with large dataframes. Dask supports the Pandas dataframe and Numpy array data structures and is able to either be run on your local computer or be scaled up to run on a cluster.

You can easily convert your Pandas dataframe to Dask which is made up of smaller split up Pandas dataframes and therefore allows a subset of Pandas query syntax.

here is an example of how you can do it:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

limdata= dd.read_csv(path_to_file_1)
df_case= dd.read_csv(path_to_file_2)

case = dd.merge(limdata, df_case, left_on='sacc_id$',right_on='sacc_id$')
```

There are tips on best practices on how to partition your dataframes to get a better performance. I reckon reading up on it. Also it is a good practice not to have special characters like $ in your column name.

Comment: thank you for your quick reply. then is it possible to store the result in csv file?

Comment: Yes. You can use it almost identical to Pandas